# c# paging issue in gridview while switching to the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a gridview. I am fetching data from database between two dates and displaying on it. When i tried to switch between two pages then instead of displaying data of next page it shows complete database data.

[image: whhe i switch to second page then instead of displaying data of nextpage it shows complete database data.]

here is my code

```
 myConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select User_id , LoginDate from LoginLog where LoginDate between
                                     ('" + TextBox1.Text + "') and ('" + TextBox2.Text + "')", myConn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        Lab4.Text = "No Records Found ";
    }
    myConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved paging issue in gridview

For this i just add single line code just above gridview1.databind();

here is my code...

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```